# How to install 3DxWare for Linux (x86-64) on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Tags: mouse, motif

Errors messages trying to install **3DxWare** on Ubuntu:

```
/etc/3DxWare/daemon/3dxsrv: error while loading shared libraries: libXm.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Errors messages trying to execute the cube demo on Ubuntu:

```
./xcube
stderr, basicwin: cannot open 9x15 font
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Installation instructions for 3DxWare for Linux (x86_64) - V 1.8.0

To install the files for 3DxWare for Ubuntu to the corresponding directories
and to run the driver you need root privileges.

Make sure you fulfill the following prerequisites:

```
You should have installed the X/Motif shared library. Where is included the libXm.so.3

    sudo apt-get install libmotif-dev

In some cases some X11 fonts may not have been installed, which are used to
draw on the device LCD.
Please make sure you have installed the 75 and/or 100DPI fonts for X11.

    apt install xfonts-75dpi
    apt install xfonts-100dpi
```

The files for the driver are provided with the following archive:

```
3dxware-linux-v1-8-0.x86_64.tar.gz
```

Please copy the file 3dxware-linux-v1-8-0.x86_64.tar.gz directly into the /tmp directory
and extract and run the script install-3dxunix.sh:

```
tar xfz 3dxware-linux-v1-8-0.x86_64.tar.gz install-3dxunix.sh
./install-3dxunix.sh
```

Please make sure the driver is started before you launch your application.

For the USB devices start the driver with the following command:

```
/etc/3DxWare/daemon/3dxsrv -d usb
```

I don't like the process in background, so I prefer to run the driver when I need it.
I created a shortcut in the desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=3DxWare
Exec=sudo /etc/3DxWare/daemon/3dxsrv -userName ${USER} -d usb
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=/<your_custom_folder>/icon.png
Name[en_US]=3DxWare
```

[image]

Demos:

```
After unpacking 3dxware-linux-v1-8-0.x86_64.tar you can find two demos:
The cube demo: /tmp/xcube and
a value demo:  /tmp/xvalue

Those are two simple demos that work with the setting "Any Application". You may copy the
binaries to your favourite location for binaries.
```

Supported devices:

- SpaceMouse Pro Wireless
- SpaceMouse Wireless
- SpaceMouse Pro
- Space Pilot Pro
- Space Pilot
- Space Explorer (Serial, USB)
- Space Navigator for Notebooks
- Space Navigator

Comment: I get `Could not open USB port or no supported device found! Exiting!` in Ubuntu 22.04. Have you made this work on ubuntu 22.04?

Answer (score 0):

The supported list doesn't mention Space Mouse Compact so I never bothered to try the official software, the desktop Icon is however a spacemouse compact. So does it support it or not?

Comment: Yes, it support. Use actually the Space Mouse Compact. But for Windows it is updated.